# jQuery: Fade in image while mouse over, fade out when mouse out

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, opacity

This should be pretty simple. Just can't get it right. I want my webpage to load images with 50% opacity. Then, on mouseover riase the opacity to 1, and back down to 0.5 again on mouseout.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='no'>
<meta charset ="utf-8"
<head>

<title>Øving 7</title>

<style type="text/css">
img {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
</style>

<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("images").hover(function() {
        $(this).animate({opacity: 1.0}, 500);
    }, function() {
        $(this).animate({opacity: 0.5}, 500);
    });
    });

</script>

</head>

<body bgcolor="lightgrey">
<h1>Oppgave 1 - jQuery</h1>

<img class="bild" src="b1.jpg" alt="Bilde1" border="0"/>
<img class="bild" src="b2.jpg" alt="Bilde2" border="0"/>
<img class="bild" src="b3.jpg" alt="Bilde3" border="0"/>
<img class="bild" src="b4.jpg" alt="Bilde4" border="0"/>
<img class="bild" src="b5.jpg" alt="Bilde5" border="0"/>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you think `$("images")` will select the `img` elements?

Comment: $("images") its should be $("img"), but use this instead $(".bild"). And a simple css will fix your problem . .bild {
  opacity: .5;
}
.bild:hover {
  opacity: 1;
} You can add transition if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `$("images")` to `$("img")` or give class `$(".build")`

```
$("img").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({opacity: 1.0}, 500);
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({opacity: 0.5}, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".vs").hover(function() {
        $(this).animate({opacity: 1.0}, 500);
    }, function() {
        $(this).animate({opacity: 0.5}, 500);
    });
    });

</script>
<style>
.vs{
 opacity: 0.5;
width:33.33%;
}
</style>
<div class="w3-row-padding w3-hide-small" style="margin:0 -16px">
<div class="w3-third w3-center">
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg" class="vs">

</div>

<div class="w3-third w3-center">
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg" class="vs">

</div>

<div class="w3-third w3-center">
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg" class="vs">

</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this with CSS not with jQuery.

```
.bild {
   opacity: 0.5;
   transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   }

   .bild:hover {
      opacity: 1;
      }
```